# Does the code below have potential memory leak?

Tags: ios

The last two lines of code below it's returning gives me a potential memory leak warning. .....Is this a true positive warning or false positive warning? If true, how do i fix it? Thanks a lot for your help!

```
-(UIImage*)setMenuImage:(UIImage*)inImage isColor:(Boolean)bColor
{ 
    int w = inImage.size.width + (_borderDeep * 2);
    int h = inImage.size.height + (_borderDeep * 2);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    CGContextRef context;

    if (YES == bColor)
    {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    }
    else
    {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
        context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaNone);        
    }

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(_borderDeep, _borderDeep, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height), inImage.CGImage);

    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context); //releasing context
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace); //releasing colorSpace

    //// The two lines of code above caused Analyzer gives me a warning of potential leak.....Is this a true positive warning or false positive warning? If true, how do i fix it?
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're leaking the `CGImage` object (that's stored in your `image` variable). You can fix this by releasing the image after creating the `UIImage`.

```
UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
CGImageRelease(image);
return uiImage;
```

The reason for this is that CoreGraphics follows the CoreFoundation ownership rules; in this case, the ["Create" rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029). Namely, functions with "Create" (or "Copy") return an object that you are required to release yourself. So in this case, `CGBitmapContextCreateImage()` is returning a `CGImageRef` that you are responsible for releasing.

---

Incidentally, why aren't you using the `UIGraphics` convenience functions to create your context? Those will handle putting the right scale on the resulting `UIImage`. If you want to match your input image, you can do that as well

```
CGSize size = inImage.size;
size.width += _borderDeep*2;
size.height += _borderDeep*2;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, inImage.scale); // could pass YES for opaque if you know it will be
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
[inImage drawInRect:(CGRect){{_borderDeep, _borderDeep}, inImage.size}];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

Comment: Really helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have to free CGImageRef you made. `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` has "create" in the name, which means (Apple is strict with its naming conventions) that you are responsible for freeing this memory.

Replace the last line with

```
UIImage *uiimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
CGImageRelease(image);
return uiimage;
```